# Why is mandatory text (CDATA) inside tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]' still missing or incorrect?

Tags: amp-html

though i spent several hours in fixing the last AMP validation error i need further assistance in solving the following error:

*The mandatory text (CDATA) inside tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]' is missing or incorrect.*

as seen on 
https://con-creat.de/detail-amp/schreiben-kann-jeder.html#development=1

i really do not understand why this error is thrown. 
Snippet as seen on https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-boilerplate.md is included and seems properly formatted.

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking at your page and there appears to be a missing whitespace character in the AMP boilerplate code. I would try removing it completely and copying and pasting it into your page again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion Andrew but that didn't work. I tried several times in intelliJ, in contao, direct with sublime but neither worked properly. :(

Comment: My bad, I should have looked at the rest of your code... Sorry about that.

Comment: Nope, my fault. Thus @Jay Gray fixed the problem on his Version you are totally right. The Problem seems to be the missing whitespace in the -keyframes- but i still have not solved the issue. The Template looks great but when viewing in Frontend all keyframe whitespace are lost.

Should be `@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{...}`
But is `@-moz-keyframes-amp-start{...}`
and i have totally no idea why contao-cms is doing that.

Comment: Fixed it. Backend option for minified markup killed it all.
I praise all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3094317/index.html

Has correction per @Andrew and several other small changes.

Also, recommend that you use `<link href='_symbol_.png' rel='shortcut icon'>` rather than `_symbol_` in your root directory. The Google CDN will then use it. As you can see, it is now lost when displayed in the CDN.

Comment: Your version works like a charm. Do you mind telling me what exactly was the big problem? Just for future issues :)

Comment: I have my own `lint` program for cleaning my AMP documents. One problem it found also was identified by @Andrew. While it's conventional to use relative addressing, IMHE absolute URL are better processed by Google CDN. This theory is not universally accepted, but it works for me and is part of my `lint` program. My `lint` also picked up the absence of the `short cut` icon per above. Please accept the answer if this hits the mark.